# Avoiding adding userID to every model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I feel like this may be a very simple question but I've been stuck for over an hour so I'm going to throw it up here and see what bites.

In my Rails app, users have pages, and pages have paragraphs. Pages have a belongs_to relationship with users, and I need to get all the paragraphs marked important for a particular user.

So the question is, using the pre-existing relationship that paragraphs have to pages and pages have to users, how can I do this?

I can't do:

`current_user.pages.paragraphs.where(important: true)`

because current_user.pages returns a collection, so it errors that there is no paragraphs method on that collection.

So do I have to just add a User field to paragraphs, and make a relationship there? So that I can do:

`current_user.paragraphs.where(important: true)`

Or is there a way to avoid doing that? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should establish a `has_many :paragraphs, through: :pages` association on your `User` model. This will create `User#paragraphs`, and that will allow you to call `current_user.paragraphs.where(important: true)` without needing to create a more complex query.

The details of this are located in `ActiveRecord::Associations.has_many` [documents here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many).

Your models would then look something like:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  has_many :pages
  has_many :paragraphs, through: :pages
  ...
end

class Page < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  has_many :paragraphs
  belongs_to :user
  ...
end

class Paragraph < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  belongs_to :page
  ...
end
```